# Изменить данные реестра WinAPI

Tags: winapi, delphi, реестр, delphi-7

Добрый день. Хочу изменить данные реестра WinAPI. 
Нашел юнит. Это только какие функции есть.

```
function RegSetString(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; Value: string): boolean;
    function RegSetMultiString(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; Value: string): boolean;
    function RegSetExpandString(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; Value: string): boolean;
    function RegSetDWORD(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; Value: Cardinal): boolean;
    function RegSetBinary(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; Value: array of Byte): boolean;
    function RegGetString(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; var Value: string): boolean;
    function RegGetMultiString(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; var Value: string): boolean;
    function RegGetExpandString(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; var Value: string): boolean;
    function RegGetDWORD(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; var Value: Cardinal): boolean;
    function RegGetBinary(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; var Value: string): boolean;
    function RegGetValueType(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; var Value: Cardinal): boolean;
    function RegValueExists(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string): boolean;
    function RegKeyExists(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string): boolean;
    function RegDelValue(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string): boolean;
    function RegDelKey(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string): boolean;
    function RegConnect(MachineName: string; RootKey: HKEY; var RemoteKey: HKEY): boolean;
    function RegDisconnect(RemoteKey: HKEY): boolean;
    function RegEnumKeys(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; var KeyList: string): boolean;
    function RegEnumValues(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; var ValueList: string): boolean;
```

Какой функцией можно заменить это действие:

```
    regst:=TRegistry.Create;
    regst.RootKey:=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  regst.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\la-la-la',true);
    regst.WRiteInteger('la-la-la',1);
    regst.CloseKey;
```

Пробовал так:

```
RegSetString(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,'Software\Microsoft\Windows\la-la-la','la-la-la','1');
```

Как сделать это? ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала создать саму функцию:

```
function RegSetString(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; Value: string): LongInt;

begin

 Result:= RegSetValue(RootKey, PWideChar(Name), REG_SZ, PChar(Value + #0), Length(Value) + 1);

end;
```

**Обновление**

Эта функция принимает только три параметра. И второй параметр нужно задавать, видимо, так:

```
'Software\Microsoft\Windows\la-la-la\la-la-la'
```

Ну а третий параметр - само значение: '1'

Comment: RegSetString(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,'Software\Microsoft\Windows\la-la-la','la-la-la','1'); , чего то так нельзя? .pas добавил в проект, RegSETString вызывается, но при компиляции пишет "Много заданных параметров", я и думаю ,может с ключем или строкой ошибся

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, этим:

```
function RegSetDWORD(RootKey: HKEY; Name: string; Value: Cardinal): boolean;
```

Чем вас не устраивает второй вариант?

```
regst := TRegistry.Create;
try
  regst.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  regst.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\la-la-la', True);
  regst.WriteInteger('la-la-la', 1);
  regst.CloseKey;
finally
  regst.Free;
end;
```